# How was this representation obtained from this submodule from Dummit and Foote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

On page 862 of D&F, we define the action of $S_{3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to be the permutation of the indices of the elementary basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. So we have a representation of $S_{3}$ into $\textrm{GL}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$, by this action, and we can obtain the $S_{3}$ invariant subspace:
$$I = \{w \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: w = \alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2 + \alpha_3 e_3, ~ \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 0 \}.$$
Then this subspace $I$ is spanned by $e_1 - e_2$ and $e_2 - e_3$. D&F claims that,
$$(1,2) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Where, this is a sub representation on the subspace $I$, but I'm confused how they got this matrix? Do they make $v_1 = e_1-e_2$  and $v_2 = e_2 - e_3$ be the new basis vectors and permute those indices, but that does not match up with the matrix above, so can anyone enlighten me as to how they obtained this matrix.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of $\sigma =(1,2)$ on your $v_1$ and $v_2$ (by permuting the underlying $e_i$) is $\sigma (v_1) = \sigma(e_1-e_2) = e_2-e_1= -v_1$ and $\sigma(v_2) = \sigma( e_2-e_3) = e_1-e_3 = v_1+v_2$.

Do you now see how they get the matrix?